# Decompiling folders inside a jar file

Tags: malware, reverse-engineering, static-analysis

I am in possession of a jar file that I have reason to believe has a RAT inside. I downloaded it inside of a virtual machine with jad installed and began to attempt to look at the source. I found that jad was useful for decompiling one file at a time, but I didn't see any obvious way to decompile folders of .class files at a time.
Is jad the best tool for this, or is there a better tool? I'm on a debian 32 bit system. Could you also tell me the best command to use if it is jad? 
In doing research on this question, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file) outdated question, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793469/how-can-i-decompile-many-jars-at-once) outdated question, but I want a more up to date solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)) has been unmaintained for a while now. For decompiling a jar, I typically use [JD-GUI](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui), just as [your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/647116/19144) proposes.